# MS Access - JOIN between pairs of fields between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, join

I have two very large tables. One with approx 57,000 rows and the other with approx 30,000 rows.

Both tables have two common fields, A Side Site and Z Side Site. I'm trying to create query that makes a table with the common A Side Site and Z Side Site fields.

example: PathListResults
A Side Site     Z Side Site
............................
San Diego        Seattle
San Francisco    Portland
Los Angeles      Las Vegas
Chicago          Indianapolis
Atlanta          New Orleans

example2: SegmentListResults
A Side Site     Z Side Site
............................
Chicago          Indianapolis
Dallas           Baltimore
Atlanta          New Orleans
New York         Brooklyn
Los Angeles      Chicago
Atlanta          Portland
San Diego        Seattle

I want a table that ends up like this....
A Side Site     Z Side Site
............................
San Diego        Seattle
Chicago          Indianapolis
Atlanta          New Orleans

When I tried to link the two fields in Design View. It produced the following code:

```
SELECT PathListResults.[A Side Site], PathListResults.[Z Side Site],
   SegmentListResults.[A Side Site], SegmentListResults.[Z Side Site]
FROM PathListResults
INNER JOIN SegmentListResults ON (PathListResults.[Z Side Site] = SegmentListResults.[Z Side Site])
   AND (PathListResults.[A Side Site] = SegmentListResults.[A Side Site]);
```

This produces a table with approx 669,000 rows which is obviously incorrect when you look at the row amount for the other two tables (10,000 max if every row in the smallest table matches the biggest table). I suspect it it is running matches for A site and Z site separately.

Comment: no. the join condition is evaluated in its entirety, since it's an "and" join. Both tables' Z values **AND** A values have to match, or the join doesn't happen.

Comment: If you think 57.000 records is *very large*, then it might be time to move to a different database.

Comment: I think it strange you got that volume of records. Is there a unique key in each table? Are the two fields in the table unique when combined together? (1) Run the above query as a select query and see how many rows are returned. (2) Place selection criteria for only one city (i.e. Chicago) and see how many records. Unless BOTH tables have lots of duplicate information...